# MySQL select multiple rows by referencing to one data field

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, having

```
===========================
= id = model_id = property =
===========================
= 14 = 1        = 1       =
===========================
= 15 = 1        = 3       =
===========================
= 16 = 2        = 1       =
```

I have a table like above and I want to select model_ids only where property equals to 1 AND 3

I'd be glad if you could show me how

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want this:

```
select model_id
from yourtable
where property in (1, 3)
group by model_id
having count(*) > 1;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1823b/7)

Or you can use the following:

```
select model_id
from yourtable t1
where property = 1
  and exists (select model_id
              from yourtable t2
              where t1.model_id = t2.model_id
                and property = 3)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1823b/8)

Answer (score 0):

#### You can use [`IN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) clause:

```
SELECT `model_id`
  FROM `table`
  WHERE `property` IN (1, 3)
```

Comment: this way the row where model_id = 2 also comes as a result but I want models only containing that both property value

Comment: You said only where property equals to 1 AND 3 should be displayed. Didn't say anything about model 2?

Answer (score 0):

```
select model_ids from yourtable where property in(1,3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT model_ids 
FROM tableName 
WHERE property in (1,3) 
GROUP BY model_ids 
HAVING COUNT( DISTINCT property ) = 2
```

Comment: thanks but still model 2 which has only the property 1 comes also as result